# Exact string matching and comparsion with with a list of strings python

Tags: python, string

What I want is to compare a string and check if it is present in a list of strings.
For example

```
'mild proliferative retinopathy'=='diabetic retinopathy' or  'moderate non proliferative retinopathy' or 'mild nonproliferative retinopathy'
```

What I want to match exactly not partially. If exact word matches then return True, instead False.

Following implementation return True on partial matching. I need exact matching

```
any('diabetic' in s for s in ['diabetic retinopathy' , 'moderate non proliferative retinopathy' ,'mild nonproliferative retinopathy'])
```

Another implementation I tried

```
'retinopathy' in str(['diabetic retinopathy' , 'moderate non proliferative retinopathy' ,'mild nonproliferative retinopathy'])
```

This also returns True on partial matching

Comment: Use regular expressions to match with word boundaries `\b` around the word. Or split the string into an array of words, and then test if the word is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `in`, use `==`:

```
any('diabetic' == s for s in ['diabetic retinopathy' , 'moderate non proliferative retinopathy' ,'mild nonproliferative retinopathy'])
```

This is because `in` checks if your `string` is present anywhere in the `string` you're comparing it with. `==` checks if the two strings are equal.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
any('diabetic' == s for s in ['diabetic retinopathy' , 'moderate non proliferative retinopathy' ,'mild nonproliferative retinopathy'])
```